# I have a data frame in R with two fields name and fruit. How can I get a list of names who have got more than one kind of fruit?

Tags: r

Here is the R code to define the data:

```
library(tidyverse)

name <- c("John","John","John","Peter","Paul","Paul", "Steven", "Steven")<p>
fruit <- c("Apple","Apple","Banana","Banana","Cherry","Cherry","Apple","Banana")<p>
grunnur <- data.frame(name,fruit) <p>
grunnur$name <- factor(grunnur$name) <p>
grunnur$fruit <- factor(grunnur$fruit) <p>
```

I know that John and Steven have tried two or more fruits, but how can I can a list with their names by using a code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` way:

1. We first group by `name`.
2. Calculate the number of distinct fruit values for each group using the `n_distinct`.
3. `filter` only those with more then one distinct fruit:

```
library(dplyr)

grunnur %>%
  summarise(n_fruits = n_distinct(fruit), .by=name) %>%
  filter(n_fruits > 1) %>%
  select(name)
```

```
    name
1   John
2 Steven
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `filter` with `n_distinct` to check if the group has more than 1 unique value. If you want to have a list of Steven and John, you could `pull` the `unique` names and `split` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse) 
grunnur %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(fruit) > 1)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name   fruit 
#>   <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 John   Apple 
#> 2 John   Apple 
#> 3 John   Banana
#> 4 Steven Apple 
#> 5 Steven Banana

grunnur %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(fruit) > 1) %>%
  pull(name) %>%
  unique() %>%
  split(., .)
#> $John
#> [1] "John"
#> 
#> $Steven
#> [1] "Steven"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`

```
subset(grunnur,  name %in% names(Filter(\(x) length(x) > 1, 
  with(unique(grunnur[c("fruit", "name")]), split(fruit, name)))))
```

-output

```
    name  fruit
1   John  Apple
2   John  Apple
3   John Banana
7 Steven  Apple
8 Steven Banana
```